# ffmpeg converting Nikon .mov file to a format for Da Vinci Resolve Linux

Tags: ffmpeg, davinci-resolve

Hi folks I've spent 2 days on this now and I'm no closer to finding the perfect ffmpeg command line to do an exact conversion of a Nikon D850 .mov file to a format that Da Vinci Resolve on Linux can import.

I've tried PRORES `ffmpeg -i input.MOV -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 3 -qscale:v 9 -vendor ap10 -pix_fmt yuv422p10le output.mov` but this takes a 2.3 Gb original file and creates one that is 16GB

I've tried mjpeg `ffmpeg -i input.MOV -vcodec mjpeg -q:v 1 -f mov output.mov` this creates a file that to my eyes doesn't seem to differ in quality but is half the size of the original.

I've tried various other things some which produce a file Da Vinci can read but all result in a file size half the original. Space is an issue for me so the ProRes is not an option, a smaller file size is of course welcome as long as I know the original quality has not been lost.

Is this reduction in file size something to be concerned about?

Can anyone recommend a way to simply do a direct conversion without modifying bitrates or quality. My eyes are a bit doddery at the moment due to some new meds I am on so while I cannot see quality differences between the originals and the converted files I would hate to convert 4 years worth of timelapse footage and discover later they lost quality.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you give any information about what the source codec in the .mov container is? If it's a common codec davinci resolve should be able to read it directly.

Also: You can't directly compare file sizes of different codecs in order to say something about quality. Highly compressed codecs like h.264 will always have a smaller file size then e.g. ProRes or DNxHR on the cost of computing power for decoding.

Answer (score 0):

I purchased Da Vinci resolve Studio Pro which imports all my files in their existing format so this can be marked as solved.